# Do I need sonar and sonar runner for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I want to set up Sonar with Jenkins. But I'm not sure if the [Sonar site](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+Jenkins+Plugin#ConfiguringSonarJenkinsPlugin-AddingSonarRunner) describes two different ways to do this or if there are two necessary steps:

As far as I understood it, it's two different ways. If this is the case, what is the difference and what are the advantages and disadvantages (between the Sonar itself and Sonar runner)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to analyse a project with SonarQube and Jenkins, here's what you need:

- A SonarQube server up and running
- A Jenkins server up and running with the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins installed and configure to point to your SonarQube server
- A job configured to run a SonarQube analysis on your project:

  - Using the default and standard SonarQube Scanner (suitable for most projects)
  - Using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (for .NET solutions)
  - Using a post build action for Maven-based projects

Everything is described more in details on the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins).

Comment: No, you're not obliged to edit settings.xml: choosing the Sonar server that you've configured in the global Jenkins settings should be enough.

Comment: The link for "your Sonar server configured..." seems to be broken. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Configuring+Jenkins+SonarQube+Plugin is probably where it went.

Comment: @IanH Thanks for the notification, I've updated the links!

Comment: Now the Post Build Action is no longer recommended: "It is no longer recommended to use SonarQube maven builder. It is preferable to set up SonarQube in the build environment and use a standard Jenkins maven target.".
So, it seems that you have to add a "sonar-project.properties" configuration file to every single job you want to analyze, using a Pre or a Post Build Step.
It is not clear how to simply configure many jobs.

Comment: Hello, If I'm not using maven, should sonar runner be on the same server than jenkins ?

Comment: The first link is dead again, I guess the correct one is now this: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins