# SonarRunner can't find sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am attempting to get Jenkins to run Sonar as a post-build step.

Jenkins runs SonarRunner [1] but this fails with:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
```

If I run `mvn sonar:sonar` [2] instead it works fine. It almost sounds like SonarRunner is ignoring pom.xml. **How do I get SonarRunner to pick up these properties from Maven?**

---

[1] `/Users/builds/.jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Default_Sonar_Runner/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://myServer:1009/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://myServer/sonar/ -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/builds/.jenkins/workspace/myProject`

[2] `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://myServer:1009/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://myServer/sonar/ -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/builds/.jenkins/workspace/myProject`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Per https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/ the desired functionality is now available.

---

What a nice way to waste an evening...

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473275/14731) Sonar Runner is not meant for Maven projects. It turns out you're supposed to look under "Post-Build Actions" (not "Post-Build Steps") and you will find "Sonar". See [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job) for more information.

Comment: As of SonarQube 5.x, the SonarQube documentation states using the Jenkins "Sonar"  post-build action is deprecated http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARNEXT/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswithMaven

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: My Jenkins tells me it deprecated but it solved my issue

Comment: This is the latest link for here. @Gili would you like to update.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
If you installed a scanner in Jenkins then just add the following 
in this location on your job
Post Steps -> Execute SonarQube Scanner -> Analysis properties

```
sonar.projectKey=myProject1
sonar.sources=.
```

**Method 2:**
Another alternative is using the deprecated method which still works fine
Post-build Actions -> SonarQube analysis with Maven

**Method 3:**
Build -> Goals and options ->  "enter the below script"
-Dmaven.test.skip=true install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ -Dsonar.branch=my-branch-1

Answer (score 0):

There is some Maven GAV info data mapped into Jenkins variables, look at this thread: [Automatically derive mandatory SonarQube properties from pom file in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884230/automatically-derive-mandatory-sonarqube-properties-from-pom-file-in-jenkins/42634941#42634941)

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration in `sonar-scanner.properties`:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.projectKey=<your project package>
sonar.projectName=<your project name with absolute path>
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```