# How to set the mandatory properties sources for Sonar in Jenkins

Tags: properties, build, jenkins, sonarqube

Hello I've a problem with the configuration of jenkins in order to use the plugin of Sonar.
I've set the properties into the file sonar-project.properties, that looks like the following code:

```
pom.groupId=groupID
pom.artifactId=artifactID

sonar.sourceEncoding=iso-8859-15
sonar.java.target=1.5
sonar.java.source=1.5
sonar.projectKey=projectkey
sonar.projectName= projectname
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
```

While I'm trying to do the building I got the following error in the console of Jenkins:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: You must define mandatory properties: sources
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.checkMandatoryProperties(Runner.java:92)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:75)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Build step '**** custom Sonar analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Do you have any suggestion? Where do I set this properties?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sonar Setup Undefined Mandatory Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204350/sonar-setup-undefined-mandatory-properties)

Answer (score 1):

"sonar.sources" property is mandatory: it tells SonarQube where your source files are located.

Everything is explained in the online documentation:

- [Analysis Parameters](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)
- [How to run an analysis with SonarQube Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)