# Sonar: You must define the following mandatory properties for unknown not resolved

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to run SonarQube on a project in java. I configured the sonar properties file and placed it in the project directory. On running the sonar.bat there is an error that asks to define the mandatory parameters. At first I assumed my properties file was wrong, but I've tried everything I can think of.

this is the current properties file

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=_newtest2
sonar.projectName=NoSqlDataModeling
sonar.projectVersion=2.0

# Path to the parent source code directory.
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing 
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=D:/eclipse workspace/NoSqlDataModeling


#Comma-separated paths to directories containing the binary files (directories with class files, in the case of Java).
sonar.binaries=D:/eclipse workspace/NoSqlDataModeling/build/classes

#Comma-separated paths to files with third-party libraries (JAR files in the case of Java). Patterns #can be used.
sonar.libraries=D:/eclipse workspace/NoSqlDataModeling/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

#language used
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Additional parameters
sonar.my.property=value
```

this is the error message

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3.1
09:58:57.783 INFO  - Load batch settings
09:58:57.901 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Rohan.Kumar\.sonar\cache
09:58:57.907 INFO  - Install plugins
09:58:57.913 INFO  - Download sonar-maven-batch-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:58.037 INFO  - Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.1.jar
09:58:58.436 INFO  - Download sonar-surefire-plugin-2.1.jar
09:58:58.540 INFO  - Download sonar-cpd-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:58.870 INFO  - Download sonar-core-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:58.956 INFO  - Download sonar-java-plugin-2.1.jar
09:58:59.097 INFO  - Download sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:59.216 INFO  - Download sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.1.jar
09:58:59.331 INFO  - Download sonar-l10n-en-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:59.350 INFO  - Download sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.1.jar
09:58:59.453 INFO  - Download sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:59.655 INFO  - Download sonar-design-plugin-4.3.1.jar
09:58:59.826 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
09:59:00.061 WARN  - H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
09:59:00.061 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
09:59:00.784 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.521s
Final Memory: 5M/19M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknow
n': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with t
he -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Should I provide comma separated paths to all the class files and java files? 
Till what depth do I provide the paths? the different class files are located in build/classes/.../.../<4 different folders that have class files inside them>
I change the project key every time as I read it has to be unique.

Comment: Did you see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204350/sonar-setup-undefined-mandatory-properties? It looks like the same problem you are having.

Comment: Nick, Yes i have and i modified the properties file too. Still didn't work

Comment: @Karthikeyan, thanks for the edit. I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: You might try putting the path values in quotes where there are spaces present. Like changing this, sonar.sources=D:/eclipse workspace/NoSqlDataModeling, to this sonar.sources="D:/eclipse workspace/NoSqlDataModeling"

Comment: hey nick, nope that didn't work.I got my hands on another properties file which seems to be working fine. It's much simpler too. but i can't see the difference between the two config files.
Here is the new config file. if you could point out what errors i was making

Comment: # Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=rohan_key2
sonar.projectName=NoSqlData
sonar.projectVersion=1.2

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.binaries=build/classes
# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
#sonar.devcockpit.userAutoMapping=true
#sonar.scm.enabled=true

Comment: I got similar issue when using cygwin to run the command. I ran sonar-runner from command prompt and everything started working.

Answer (score 16):

How to Upload a Project to SonarQube:

1) Startup SonarQube. You should be able to see it if you type localhost:9000 into your browser.

2) In command prompt, cd to the directory of your project
[image]

3) Make sure the root folder of your project has “sonar-project.properties” file and that it is configured. If your project doesn’t have the “sonar-project.properties” file, it will get this error= [Sonar Setup Undefined Mandatory Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204350/sonar-setup-undefined-mandatory-properties)

My “sonar-project.properties” file for my VendingMachineEmulator app looks like this:
[image]

4) In command prompt, now type “C:\sonar-scanner\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\bin\sonar-scanner.bat”. Alternatively, you could’ve also type “C:\sonar-scanner\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\bin\sonar-runner.bat” too. I’m not sure what the difference is. Make sure the directory you are in is still the main folder of your project.

5) Done! Refresh localhost:9000 and check if the project is there.

Comment: Same as above Answer along with few more sonar properties 
`sonar.projectKey=MyWebApp
sonar.projectBaseDir=./MyWebApp
sonar.projectName=MyWebApp
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=./src/main/java
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=.
sonar.scm.disabled=True
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 6):

Those who are getting "EXECUTION FAILURE" on running sonar-runner in the project folder add

`-Dproject.settings=./sonar-project.properties`

As it can't able to find setting file, you have to mention it explicitly

sonar-project.properties is the file name in my project where I have gave projectKey, projectName

For me,
Run sonar runner with the above mentioned argument. Sonar runner was there in the folder path sonar-plugin\agent\sonar-plugin-agent\sonar-qube-runner\bin\sonar-runner or add it in environment path

`sonar-runner -Dproject.settings=./sonar-project.properties`

Comment: You rock dude. For bamboo users, I added to "Additional parameters" the value: -Dproject.settings=./sonar-project.properties    Thank you.!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

Try running sonar-scanner command from the directory where sonar-project.properties lies.

I faced same problem and later found I was running the command from the different directory.