# Automatically derive mandatory SonarQube properties from pom file in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**Situation:**

I want to analyze my project with SonarQube (5.4) triggered by Jenkins (1.642.4). It is a java project build with maven.

I see two ways to trigger the analysis:

1. Post Build Action "SonarQube analysis with maven" but it's **deprecated**, so I don't want to use it
2. Post Build Step "Execute SonarQube Scanner", is the recommended way.

**Problem:**

If I use the deprecated Post Build Action, the properties for sonar project configuration are derived automatically from the project pom.

It I use the recommended Post Build Step, I receive the Exception

> You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources

**Undesired Solution**:

The solution is to provide the required properties, via sonar-project.properties file in the java project or via parameters in Jenkins step.

IMHO: this is duplication. All relevant information is defined in the Maven pom: projectKey can be derived from artifactId, projectName and projectVerstion are same properties in maven. Especially the projectVersion is critical. I don't want to update the project version after each release (or write some code in release plugin to update it automatically).

**What I want**

I want to use the recommended Post Build Step in Jenkins, without redefine all project properties for all my project to make sonar happy. Instead sonar/jenkins/plugin/whatever should derive the properties from my maven pom file. Is there an additional plugin I can use? Can I reconfigure my Jenkins-Sonar-Plugin?

I don't want to provide any sonar specific information in my pom/project, because the project shouldn't care about sonar. It should contain only information required to build the project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven) (although slightly confusing, see edit below) explains how to use a generic post-build step (leveraging environment variables), instead of the deprecated post-build action. in short:

- install latest SonarQube Plugin (v2.4 as of now) in Jenkins
- in System Config under SonarQube servers: check `Enable injection of SonarQube server configuration as build environment variables`
- in the configuration of your Maven project:

  - check `Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment`
  - add a post-build step `Invoke top-level Maven targets` and leverage the injected environment variables in the `Goals` field e.g.:

    > $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN

**Edit**: when [the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven) says `The Post-build Action for Maven analysis is deprecated.` , it refers to the old post-build **action**  which is not documented anymore. The paragraph after that warning (summarized in this answer) really is the recommended procedure. Illustration [here](http://i68.tinypic.com/x4er8y.png) if it's still not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but in the linked documentation you can see the following text: "The Post-build Action for Maven analysis is deprecated.The Post-build Action for Maven analysis is deprecated." So unfortunatly this solution doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the documentation: what is deprecated is the Post-Build **Action**. What is described in my answer and in the documentation (below the warning) is the recommended way using a standard Maven build step (and environment variable injection). See this [illustration](http://i68.tinypic.com/x4er8y.png).

Comment: You are right. This maven target is executed as a post build STEP. So the deprecation is not referred to that solution. I will remove my answer, because as you have said, it's a bad idea because of the not automated project structure usage. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Using SonarQube Scanner as a post build step you can configure it with at least this properties in Analysis properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=${POM_ARTIFACTID}
sonar.projectName=${POM_DISPLAYNAME}
sonar.projectVersion=${POM_VERSION}
sonar.sources=src
sonar.java.binaries=target
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

**POM_*** variables are mapped by Jenkins from Maven GAV info, look here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/933/files