# Derive mandatory SonarQube properties from pom file in Jenkins with SonarQube Jenkins Plung

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, properties, sonarqube

I just use the SonarQube-Plugin for Jenkins and configured the Jenkins job to execute the SonarQube Scanner. If I'm leaving the analysis properties in the UI and the sonar-scanner.properties blank the mandatory properties are missing. According to [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) question at least the `sonar.projectKey` should be automatically derived from the maven properties `<groupId>:<artifactId>`. If I set the `sonar.projectKey` and the `sonar.sources` properties directly everything works fine. But how can I achieve that the the maven properties `<groupId>:<artifactId>` are used by the plugin?

**Edit:** If I set the Analysis properties in the UI to:
`sonar.projectKey=${POM_GROUPID}:${POM_ARTIFACTID}` and `sonar.sources=.` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634941/8027088)
it works fine. But it has no real advantage because I have to insert the same information to every job. It would be better if I can set these properties in a central file like the sonar-scanner.properties because all project dependent information is set by maven properties.

My [configuration of the Post-Build-Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubVAR.png)

Comment: do you use the last jenkins sonarqube plugin ? your screenshot seems old

Comment: I'm using the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins in Version 2.61, my Jenkins has version 2.46.

Answer (score 1):

For a Maven project, you should better use the scanner for Maven. Enable "Prepare SonarQube environment" feature and simply use a standard Maven step to run mvn sonar:sonar.

Documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After messing around with different JDKs the maven goal variant works fine, except the fact that I don't know where to put properties like `sonar.scm.disabled=true`. I tried to set it in sonar.properties and in sonar-scanner.properties and it doesn't work in neither of them. As stated in my initial question I would like to put this in a central place. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using Maven, a good way to share a property with all your projets is to put it in the parent pom of your organization (even if I don't recommend disabling SCM feature).