# sonar jenkins run tries connecting to h2

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube 4.2  -
it is running against Oracle XE 
am running Jenkins on Tomcat 6.x

I have sonar configured with Jenkins ( NOT Sonar runner )

am trying to run a Jenkins job and then invoke Sonar  through :
"Invoke top level maven targets"

Here I am invoking the command:

-e clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports -Dsonar.projectVersion=ABC-${BUILD_NUMBER} -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true

The issue is that the job fails with the following exception:

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.2

[INFO] [16:10:29.258] Load batch settings

[INFO] [16:10:30.038] User cache: C:\Users\xyz\.sonar\cache
[INFO] [16:10:30.053] Install plugins
[INFO] [16:10:30.381] Install JDBC driver
[WARN] [16:10:30.381] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
[INFO] [16:10:30.381] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar

[ERROR] Fail to connect to database
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Fail to connect to database

Connection refused: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Fail to connect to database
```

I have checked sonar.properties and it is configured to work with OracleXE

My project that is executed has the following entry in its pom ( maven2 )
   `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
    </plugin>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure maven to actually use the correct database when you use the maven goal. This is done in your `settings.xml` file.

Please refer to the documentation for how to configure it: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven

Comment: Thanks @benzonico - but I do not think that this is needed if I am invoking maven through jenkins and in jenkins I am configuring sonar credentials including database details - and I am positive I have had it work this way some months back without having the need to configure database in settings.xml

Comment: got it to work-the link on so helped : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472283/do-i-need-sonar-and-sonar-runner-for-jenkins 
I did not have sonar runner installed - was confused Jenkins was providing sonar-runner and sonar - so for those who are confused - visit the link - has the details 
My problem was idiotic - I was trying to run sonar through **Post Steps Invoke Top level Maven targets** and when I changed it to **Post-build actions Sonar' it worked for me - hope that this is useful to others and yes you do not need to configure database in settings.xml in this case