# Can SonarQube fetch Data from a Git Repository?

Tags: git, sonarqube, bitbucket

I have a SonarQube Instance running on my Debian 7 machine, and now I want that every time I push something in my git repository (BitBucket), the SonarQube Server automatically starts the scan from my repo.

Is this possible? And how?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This is not the responsibility of SonarQube to handle this part. Instead, you should configure a CI server (like Jenkins) that will do this job: check if your repo has been updated, and if so, trigger a SonarQube analysis.

You can read the following answer that is not exactly related to your question but that describes what you should do: [Do I need sonar and sonar runner for Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472283/do-i-need-sonar-and-sonar-runner-for-jenkins)

Comment: while I agree with this in principle, for my code base with lots of modules and lots of class files, the build time increases from 12 minutes to 96 minutes and ideally I want to run the analysis on every branch (to see the diff between two branches to help with code review)