# SonarQube Integration with GIT

Tags: git, sonarqube, integration

I have a requirement where in if a developer commits code in git Sonarqube should automatically do a code analysis and display in the dash board. Sonarqube is in AWS Ubuntu instance. Code is written in c#?

I have installed Sonarqube ,Git and sonar Github plugin and generated ssh-key for sonar and copied to git. In Github plugin for GitHub API Endpoint what should be given?
Please let me know any further steps to integrate git commits in Sonarqube?

Comment: Pull request analysis does not submit an analysis report to SonarQube, thus the project homepage will not be updated. What it does do is comment your PR with new issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SonarQube fetch Data from a Git Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874890/can-sonarqube-fetch-data-from-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup a build server (like "Jenkins" or "Bamboo" or similar) that gets triggered by git commits, checks out the code and runs a SonarQube analysis with the msbuild scanner.

You could also consider to use a cloud service for the builds - like "travis" for example.