# FATAL: No SonarQube installation assigned for this job. There are 0 available installations that can be configured

Tags: java, jenkins, build, sonarqube

I'm trying to configure code quality check with SonarQube in Jenkins. I've added in Jenkins Sonar - plugin and configured it in Manage Jenkins - Configure system - MSBuild SonarQube Runner [image: Error]

But when I try to buid my project with Jenkins, I get the error:

> FATAL: No SonarQube installation assigned for this job. There are 0
>   available installations that can be configured. If you want to
>   reassign a lot of jobs to a different SonarQube installation see
>   <strike>http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Reassign+Jobs+to+Another+SonarQube+Instance</strike>
>   Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as
>   failure channel stopped

**EDIT**

The page cited in the error message has moved. The new URL is: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Reassign+Jobs+to+Another+SonarQube+Instance

Comment: Do you have a sonarqube server running? Is the runner configured to publish to the server?

Comment: Yes, I've started sonarqube server. About second question: I'm not sure that I've made all configurations
You can see my settings on a picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3EL.png
Thanks ahead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need sonar and sonar runner for Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472283/do-i-need-sonar-and-sonar-runner-for-jenkins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Maven or Ant steps, you need to set the variables to point the scanner to the sonarqube server.

[image: maven]

For Standalone, you can define the sonar server installation directly.

[image: standalone]

[Instructions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AddingSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild)

Comment: That's required when you're using for instance a Maven build step for analysis, but not for the "Stand alone SonarQube Analysis" or "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" steps, the latter of which the OP is presumably using.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts of global configuration. You have done the first. Now you must configure at least one SonarQube server.

Look for the section toward the bottom of the page labeled either "SonarQube", or "SonarQube server" and configure the server instance you expect analysis to submit data to.

Comment: Thank you, guys, it helped)))